# TextFormField with bloc pattern is Subbmiting null

Tags: forms, dart, flutter, bloc

When using TextFormField, I am not able to add or update data, the data submitted to the db is always null or I get a NoSuchMethodErrorerror

`I/flutter ( 6511): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null`

I have build the Bloc as so:

```
class ProductsBloc {

  String id;
//  Product _product;


  // ignore: close_sinks
//  static final _productController = BehaviorSubject<Product>();
//  Stream<Product> get productOut => _productController.stream;

  // ignore: close_sinks
  final _id = BehaviorSubject<int>();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final _title = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final _message = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final _price = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Observable<int> get idOut => _id.stream;
  Observable<String> get titleOut => _title.stream.transform(_validateTitle);
  Observable<String> get message => _message.stream;
  Observable<String> get price => _price.stream;

  Function(int) get changeId => _id.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeTitle => _title.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeMessage => _message.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePrice => _price.sink.add;

  final _validateTitle = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (title, sink){
    if(title.isNotEmpty){
      sink.add(title);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Add some text');
    }
  });

  Future<void> createProduct({title}) {
    return db.createProduct(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(), title.value, _message.value, _price.value);
  }
```

the ui like so:

```
class _ProductEditPageState extends State<ProductEditPage> {

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _titleFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();

  final id;
  final title;
  final message;
  final price;

  _ProductEditPageState(this.id, this.title, this.message, this.price);

  final Map<String, dynamic> _formData = {
    'title': null,
    'message': null,
    'price': null,
    'image': 'assets/food.jpg'
  };

  Widget _buildTitleTextField(ProductsBloc productBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: productBloc.titleOut,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return TextFormField(
          focusNode: _titleFocusNode,
          onSaved: (String value){ _formData['title'] = value;},
          initialValue: title,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title', errorText: snapshot.error),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and the submit like this. 
the submitted data as this catches the error NoSuchMethodFound if I change the submit to no argument or the argument it fills the db with null.

```
child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: targetPadding / 2),
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildTitleTextField(productBloc, ),
                _buildDescriptionTextField(productBloc),
                _buildPriceTextField(productBloc),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(id != null) {
                      productBloc.updateData(id);
                    }
                    else{
                      productBloc.createProduct(
                        title: _formData['title'],
                      );
                    }
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
```

here is also my model

```
class Product {

  final db = Firestore.instance.collection('products');

  Future<void> createProduct(String docId, String title, String message, String price) async {
    await db.document(docId).setData({'id': docId, 'title': title, 'message': message, 'price': price});
  }

  void readData(String docId){
    db.document(docId).get();
  }

  Future<void> deleteData(String docId) async {
    await db.document(docId).delete();
  }

  Future<void> updateData(String docId, String title, String message, String price) async {
    await db.document(docId).updateData({'title': title, 'message': message, 'price': price});
  }

}

Product db = Product();
```

I'm also using the provider package from flutter so I think the provider is right:

```
   return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<ThemeBloc>(
          value: ThemeBloc(),
        ),
        Provider<UserBloc>(
          value: UserBloc(),
        ),
        Provider<ProductsBloc>(
          value: ProductsBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
```

using textFields is working fine but I need to see the form filled with some initial data before editing, so obviously I need to have TextFormFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty confusing, but as far as I can see you write to `_formData['title']` in `onSaved`, yet you never call `FormState.save()`.

Have you tried calling `_formKey.currentState.save()` in the `onPressed` of the save button?